# ListView with CAB - how to make item clickable but not selectable?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter. Some items can be selected, other not. Selecting a selectable item initializes CAB.

To disable items selection I override `isEnabled()` in the adapter class. But disabled items don't fire `onItemClick()` callbacks as well.

How can I make items clickable and not selectable in CAB mode at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little to late, but my solution for this was to add a click listener to the respective view in the adapter. From there, you can use a callback implemented by you to notify your UI or something.

Comment: Yes, I followed similar approach: added onClick and onLongClick listeners, and also added `isSelectable()` method to list adapter, which returned boolean based on additional data (basically, clicked item status), whether to enable long clicks or not